# jqGridRender: how can I filter data as I type?

Tags: php, jquery, filter, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid and jqGridRender. The question is: can I automatically filter data in a column as I type characters in the filter box?
For example if you take the demo "Search/Filtering --> Toolbar search with operations" at the page http://www.trirand.net/demo/php/jqgrid/, I want to automatically filter rows while I'm typing in the ShipName column. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you definitely can. From the following link: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching

searchOnEnter: Determines how the search should be applied. If the option is **false** then the search is performed immediately when the user pres some character

```js
$("#orders").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{stringResult: true, searchOnEnter : false});
```